# Calculate Each dropbox folder size recursively using python api

Tags: python, file, dropbox, dropbox-api

**EDIT:** I want to calculate each folder size not just entire dropbox size... My code is working fine for whole dropbox size

I am having difficulty in calculating each folder size of dropbox using python api
as dropbox returns folder size as zero

here's my code so far but it's giving me wrong answer

```
  def main(dp_path):
   a=  client.metadata(dp_path)
   size_local = 0
   for x in a['contents']:
     if x['is_dir']==False:
       global size
       size += int(x['bytes'])
       size_local += int(x['bytes'])

       #print "Total size so far :"+str(size/(1024.00*1024.00))+" Mb..." 


     if x['is_dir']==True:
       a = main(str(x['path']))
       print str(x['path'])+" size=="+str(a/(1024.00*1024.00))+" Mb..."

     return size_local+size


 if __name__ == '__main__':
   global size
   size=0
   main('/')
   print str(size/(1024.00*1024.00))+" Mb"
```

Comment: Do you want to do this for the local or the remote files?

Comment: Of Course remote files

Comment: Where do you initialize `global size` (to zero)?

Comment: @martineau in main itself , I have edited the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: It seems I misunderstood the question. Here's code that prints out the sizes of each folder (in order of decreasing size):

```
from dropbox.client import DropboxClient
from collections import defaultdict

client = DropboxClient('<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>')

sizes = {}
cursor = None
while cursor is None or result['has_more']:
    result = client.delta(cursor)
    for path, metadata in result['entries']:
        sizes[path] = metadata['bytes'] if metadata else 0
    cursor = result['cursor']

foldersizes = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for path, size in sizes.items():
    segments = path.split('/')
    for i in range(1, len(segments)):
        folder = '/'.join(segments[:i])
        if folder == '': folder = '/'
        foldersizes[folder] += size

for folder in reversed(sorted(foldersizes.keys(), key=lambda x: foldersizes[x])):
    print '%s: %d' % (folder, foldersizes[folder])
```

---

**EDIT**: I had a major bug in the second code snippet (the `delta` one), and I've now tested all three and found them all to report the same number.

This works:

```
from dropbox.client import DropboxClient

client = DropboxClient('<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>')

def size(path):
    return sum(
        f['bytes'] if not f['is_dir'] else size(f['path'])
        for f in client.metadata(path)['contents']
    )

print size('/')
```

But it's much more efficient to use [`/delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta):

```
sizes = {}
cursor = None
while cursor is None or result['has_more']:
    result = client.delta(cursor)
    for path, metadata in result['entries']:
        sizes[path] = metadata['bytes'] if metadata else 0
    cursor = result['cursor']

print sum(sizes.values())
```

And if you truly just need to know the overall usage for the account, you can just do this:

```
quota_info = client.account_info()['quota_info']
print quota_info['normal'] + quota_info['shared']
```

Comment: Actually I want to calculate each folder size individually not just the entire dropbox quota

Comment: It's faster because it uses `delta` instead of `metadata`, which is a much more efficient way to enumerate everything in a Dropbox, since it involves many fewer calls to the server.